# Why doesn't CKEditor run editorConfig function

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I'm trying to specify an editorConfig function to decide if I need to hide certain plugins depending on context. For whatever reason the function is not executing.  Any ideas?

Check here:

http://jsfiddle.net/EpokK/B4yGJ/

and add the following:

```
 CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config )
    {
        alert("test");
    };
```

I tried before and after

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
```

but neither worked.

Any ideas?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you place that function in the `config.js`? As I understand you put it in the same file as `CKEDITOR.replace()` call.

So what happens is that `config.js` is loaded when you call `CKEDITOR.replace()` and it overwrites the `CKEDITOR.editorConfig` property that you set.

What you should do is either putting your config in the `config.js` file or passing it directly to the `CKEDITOR.replace()` function.

Read more about [configuring CKEditor in the documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration).

Comment: Thanks yeah. I realized that later. I thought I could specify a config after the replace.